# babel not transpiling npm package - requires /src after package-name

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'm developing an NPM package and when using yarn link to link it into a test repo, the import requires `/src` appended to the package name.

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ]
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        ["env", {
          "targets": { "node": true }
        }]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Package json main: `"main": "dist/main.js",`

Webpack config (using webpack 4):

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './src/index.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'json-loader'
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

src/index.js

```
export default () => { ... }
```

For clarity, this works fine in the test repo:

```
import myDefaultFunction from 'package-name/src'
```

but this does not (and this is what I want to work *instead*:

```
import myDefaultFunction from 'package-name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign `"main": "src/index.js"` in your module `package.json`

**main**

> The main field is a module ID that is the primary entry point to your
>   program. That is, if your package is named foo, and a user installs
>   it, and then does require("foo"), then your main module's exports
>   object will be returned.
>
> This should be a module ID relative to the root of your package
>   folder.
>
> For most modules, it makes the most sense to have a main script and
>   often not much else.

And if you want to transpile your module while developing, you should include your module in `webpack.config` babel-loader options

Comment: but webpack/babel is transpiling everything into `dist/main.js`. what needs to be included in webbpack config?